# jQuery mobile doesn't trigger pageshow code between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am writing a jQuery mobile app that contains two HTML pages. When user navigates from index.html page to search.html page, jQuery should load elements into search.html page.

However, things seems to gone wrong. The script doesn't work as expected.

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" ></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mahidol.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css"></link>
<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<!-- Cordova sh*ts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/parameterHandler.js"></script>
<script src="js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <a href="prefs.html" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear">Preferences</a>
      <h1><img src="logo.png" height="15px">&nbsp;Contact</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <form class="ui-filterable">
        <a href="search.html" class="ui-btn" data-transition="flip">Search from name</a>
        <input id="filterBoxList" data-type="search" placeholder="Type here to search from department list">
      </form>
      <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBoxList" id="list_dept">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

## search.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" ></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mahidol.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css"></link>
<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<!-- Cordova shits -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/parameterHandler.js"></script>
<script src="js/default.js"></script>
<style>
  #listie small{
    color: #ccc !important;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="search">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <a href="prefs.html" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear">Preferences</a>
      <h1><img src="logo.png" height="15px">&nbsp;Contact</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <form class="ui-filterable">
        <a href="#index" class="ui-btn" data-transition="flip">Search from dept. list</a>
        <input id="filterBoxName" data-type="search" placeholder="Type here to search from name">
      </form>
      <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBoxName" id="listie">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

## default.js (loaded the last)

```
$(document).on("pageshow","search.html",function(){
  var chx = 0;
  var m="";
  var k=[];
  $.mobile.loading( "show", {
          text: 'Loading',
          textVisible: true
  });
  if(loaded == false) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
  {
    for (var t in JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hr')))
    {
      m += "<li><a href='#view?id=" + t + "'>" + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hr'))[t].Name + " <small>" + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hr'))[t].Surname + "</small></a></li>";
    }
    $('#listie').append(m).listview('refresh');
    loaded = true;
  }
  $.mobile.loading( "hide" );
});
```

Things seems to be nice when the "search" page div is placed inside index.html (and the code is linked in single page, not two). However it does break when I tried splitting up the files into two files.

Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, solved...

Even though the div is on the same file, when using `$(document).on("pageshow",src,function(){...});` to point to src, makes sure that src points to the div ID, not the file itself.

In this case, it's `$(document).on("pageshow","#search",function(){...});`.